# ASP.NET MVC 3 multilingual website with Mustache templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, multilingual, mustache

Was just wondering what the best approach is when creating a multi-lingual website that uses Mustache templates (or any other templating library). If for example you had the following template:

```
<table class="tablesorter zebra-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Comments</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {{#list}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{Name}}</td>
            <td>{{Description}}</td>
            <td>{{Comments}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/list}}
</tbody>
</table>
```

What would be the best way to display langauge specific text for the table headings ('Name', 'Description', 'Comments'). Render on the server maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much information for a SO answer, *so* I will refer you to [Scott Hanselman's blog post on the topic](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would with Mustache if you want a clean platform neutral solution. The Hanselman approach is for .Net only.